# Trying to find a manga where the Mc discovers that hero is a girl

Tags: story-identification, manga

If I remember correctly, the story is set in an academy where the main character fights the hero but remains in second place. I remember a specific scene after the battle where the main character loses again, and then takes a shower. The main character accidentally discovers that the hero is a woman, not a man.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What kind of academy is it?  What are the fantasy/science fiction elements of the story?

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[The Reward For Keeping Quiet Was Sex With Girls Dressed As Men](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/63jhfus/kuchidome-no-gohoubi-wa-dansou-otome-to-icha-ero-desu)***...?

> Kay Brennan is a hero, no doubt about that. They're the strongest person in their school in terms of combat strength and magical power. Compared to Kay, Dino Turner - the eternal 2nd place - might as well be nothing, and as such Dino has declared Kay to be his archrival. However, Kay has a secret: she's actually a girl crossdressing as a boy. And Dino is the only one who knows her true nature.

As noted in the summary, Kay Brennan -- secretly a girl who crossdresses as a boy -- is a hero and the strongest person in their school, while Dino Turner is eternally in second place.

Dino loses a swordfight to Kay in the first chapter, and they both take a shower afterward.

Note that the story includes magicians and such, so it is on-topic for this site. It also includes sex scenes and quite a lot of nudity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. Thank you ☆*: .｡. o(≧▽≦)o .｡.:*☆

Comment: @OniFang - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].